# How to generate accents similar to `\ddot, \dddot` with marks other than \dot?

Tags: accents

I'd like to create math-mode accents similar to `\ddot{x}, \dddot{x}`, but with marks other than a `\dot`. Specifically, I'm interested in the following marks:

- `\acute`
- `\asteraccent`
- `\grave`
- `\ocirc`
- `\times`

For instance, `\aacute{x}` will add two consecutive acute accents over the letter `x`, and `\ooocirc{y}` will add three consecutive circles over the letter `y`.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: the answer depends on the case you have in mind. dot, double dot etc are defined accents in the font so the best way is to use a font that has these accents (if such a font exists) the details depend there if you are using pdftex and classic tex fomts or using opentype. Alternatively you can "fake" accents by constructing a small alignment within tex.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I'm using lualatex.

Comment: yes but what math fonts are you using, classic tex math tfm fonts or unicode-math and opentype fonts

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I don't know. How can I find out? My preamble has a `\usepackage{unicode-math}`. Does it mean I use unicode-math and opentype fonts?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: In any case, since I currently need this notation only for personal use, I have no problem using whichever font is most convenient for generating the effects I desire.

Comment: yes you are using opentype math fonts

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer by @egreg does not solve two probems: The `\scriptstyle` and `\scriptscriptstyle` are not provided and kerning with `\skewchar` is not supported. The second one is TeX internal for better horizontal position of the accent. So, my suggestion (below) solves both these problems.

The generic `\maccentX` macro is created and double and triple acute accents are shown. You can create another accents analogically.

The internal macro `\maccentX` takes four parameters: 1 accented base, 2: accent, 3: empty or shifting up, 4: empty or scale factor. If you are using classical accents then third and fourth parameters must be empty. If you are using special symbol as an accent then these parameters can be set to appropriate values. For example, `\aacute` is derived from `\acute` (classical math accents): the 3. and 4. parameters are empty. But `\astacc` is derived from `\ast` character and it is raised up to 1.2ex and scaled by 0.6 scaling factor in our example.

```
\newcount\mstylenum 
\def\varstyle#1{\mathchoice{\mstylenum=0 #1}{\mstylenum=1 #1}{\mstylenum=2 #1}{\mstylenum=3 #1}}
\def\usestyle{\ifcase\mstylenum \displaystyle\or\textstyle\or\scriptstyle\or\scriptscriptstyle\fi}
\def\usemfont{\ifcase\mstylenum \textfont\or\textfont\or\scriptfont\or\scriptscriptfont\fi}

\def\aacute#1{\maccentX{#1}{\acute{}\mkern2.7mu\acute{}}{}{}}
\def\aaacute#1{\maccentX{#1}{\acute{}\mkern2.7mu\acute{}\mkern2.7mu\acute{}}{}{}}

\def\ggrave#1{\maccentX{#1}{\grave{}\mkern2.7mu\grave{}}{}{}}
\def\gggrave#1{\maccentX{#1}{\grave{}\mkern2.7mu\grave{}\mkern2.7mu\grave{}}{}{}}

\def\oocirc#1{\maccentX{#1}{\ocirc{}\mkern4.4mu\ocirc{}}{}{}}
\def\ooocirc#1{\maccentX{#1}{\ocirc{}\mkern4.4mu\ocirc{}\mkern4.4mu\ocirc{}}{}{}}

\def\astacc#1{\maccentX{#1}{\ast}{1.2}{.6}}
\def\aastacc#1{\maccentX{#1}{\ast\ast}{1.2}{.6}}
\def\aaastacc#1{\maccentX{#1}{\ast{\ast}\ast}{1.2}{.5}}

\def\bullacc#1{\maccentX{#1}{\bullet}{1.15}{.45}}
\def\bbullacc#1{\maccentX{#1}{\bullet\bullet}{1.2}{.45}}
\def\bbbullacc#1{\maccentX{#1}{\bullet{\bullet}\bullet}{1.2}{.45}}

\def\maccentX#1#2#3#4{
   \varstyle{
      \setbox0=\hbox{$\usestyle#1$}
      \setbox1=\hbox{$\usestyle#1\Umathchar 0 1 \skewchar\usemfont1$} 
      \setbox2=\hbox{$\usestyle#1\kern0pt\Umathchar 0 1 \skewchar\usemfont1$}
      \dimen0\ht0
      \advance\dimen0 by -\fontdimen5\usemfont1
      \ifx^#3^\else \advance\dimen0 by#3\fontdimen5\usemfont1 \fi
      \dimen1=\wd1 \advance\dimen1 by-\wd2  % skewchar correction
      \ifdim\dimen1=0pt \dimen1=.15\ht0 \fi % slant correction
      \vbox{\baselineskip=0pt \lineskiplimit=-\maxdimen
         \halign{##\cr
             \hidewidth \kern2\dimen1 \maccentS{#2}{#4}\hidewidth\cr
             \noalign{\kern\dimen0}
             $\usestyle#1$\cr
         }}
}}
\def\maccentS#1#2{\ifx^#2^$\usestyle#1$\else
   \setbox0=\hbox{$\usestyle#1$}%
   \dimen0=#2\wd0 \wd0=0pt \ht0=#2\ht0 \dp0=#2\dp0
   \hbox{\pdfsave \pdfsetmatrix{#2 0 0 #2}\box0 \pdfrestore \kern\dimen0}%
   \fi
}
\ifx\pdfsetmatrix\undefined
   \ifx\pdfextension\undefined % XeTeX setting
       \def\pdfsave{\special{pdf:literal q}}
       \def\pdfrestore{\special{pdf:literal Q}}
       \def\pdfsetmatrix#1{\special{pdf:literal #1 0 0 cm}}
   \else                       % LuaTeX setting
       \def\pdfsave       {\pdfextension save\relax}
       \def\pdfrestore    {\pdfextension restore\relax}
       \def\pdfsetmatrix  {\pdfextension setmatrix}
\fi\fi

$\aacute b, \aacute d, \aacute x, \aaacute x, \quad
 \scriptstyle \aacute b, \aacute d, \aacute x, \aaacute x$

\bye
```

[image: maccentX]

The example above works with XeTeX or LuaTeX because `\Umathchar` primitive is used. If you are using pdftex then you must declare

```
 \newcount\tmpnum
```

and you must use following `\setbox` lines:

```
      \tmpnum=\skewchar\usemfont1 \advance\tmpnum by256
      \setbox0=\hbox{$\usestyle#1$}
      \setbox1=\hbox{$\usestyle#1\mathchar\tmpnum$} 
      \setbox2=\hbox{$\usestyle#1\kern0pt\mathchar\tmpnum$}
```

Comment: Thanks. This solution works great with acute and grave accents, but how can I modify it to work with a circle, say, or a star, as in egreg's answer?

Comment: @EvanAad I supposed that you are using packages where your mentioned macros `\asteraccent` or `\ocirc` for single accents are provided (for example from unicode-math, I don't know), so you can do simply `\asteraccent{}\mkern?mu\asteraccent{}`. But, if these accents are not provided then we have to prepare them.

Comment: My preamble has `\usepackage{unicode-math,mathtools}\setmathfont{XITS math}`. I tried your code with `\asteraccent` as well as with `\ocirc`. While it works, it doesn't look as good as with the acute and grave accents, because the marks are crammed together.

Comment: @EvanAad If you haven't such macros like `\asteraccent` then I recommend to search into used math-unicoded font: is something like this in it? If no, then we need to do some tricks. For example, the answer from @egreg used "faked" math-accent from accents package. But this solution cannot work in `\scriptstyle` or `\scriptscriptstyle`. His first sequence that this is only a task for reader is only alibism. It is not so simple because "faked accents" use `\scriptscriptstyle` directly and his macro `\genericmathaccent` uses `\scriptstyle` directly.

Comment: @EvanAad I made XITS math work and I tried `\asteraccent`. You need to insert `\mkern6mu` between two `\asteraccent{}` in the `\aasteraccent` definition and `\mkern4.2mu` between two `\ocirc{}`. And three aster accents looks too big. But my answer is not preferred in this thread, so I am not ready to add next special code.

Comment: Just one last question, please. egreg's answer works also with marks such as `\bullet`. Could you please explain how to modify your answer to work with a `\bullet`?

Comment: If you add support for bullets and similar marks, I'll mark your answer as the preferred one.

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate your addition. However, I use luatex as the TeX engine, so this is not useful to me at the moment.

Comment: @EvanAad OK, I added new version on my code which works in XeTeX and LuaTeX.

Answer (score 8):

I leave to the reader how to make the symbols scale in subscripts and superscripts.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{accents}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\newcommand{\astdot}[1]{\accentset{*}{#1}}
\newcommand{\astddot}[1]{\accentset{*\mkern-1mu*}{#1}}
\newcommand{\astdddot}[1]{\accentset{*\mkern-1mu*\mkern-1mu*}{#1}}

\newcommand{\circdot}[1]{\accentset{\circ}{#1}}
\newcommand{\circddot}[1]{\accentset{\circ\mkern-1mu\circ}{#1}}
\newcommand{\circdddot}[1]{\accentset{\circ\mkern-1mu\circ\mkern-1mu\circ}{#1}}

\newcommand{\genericmathaccenti}[2]{%
  \genericmathaccent{#1{}}{#2}%
}
\newcommand{\genericmathaccentii}[2]{%
  \genericmathaccent{#1{}\mkern3mu#1{}}{#2}%
}
\newcommand{\genericmathaccentiii}[2]{%
  \genericmathaccent{#1{}\mkern3mu#1{}\mkern3mu#1{}}{#2}%
}
\newcommand{\genericmathaccent}[2]{%
  \vbox{\offinterlineskip\ialign{%
    ##\cr
    \hidewidth$\scriptstyle#1$\hidewidth\cr
    \noalign{\kern-.5ex}
    $#2$\cr}%
  }%
}
\newcommand{\gravedot}[1]{\genericmathaccenti{\grave}{#1}}
\newcommand{\graveddot}[1]{\genericmathaccentii{\grave}{#1}}
\newcommand{\gravedddot}[1]{\genericmathaccentiii{\grave}{#1}}

\newcommand{\acutedot}[1]{\genericmathaccenti{\acute}{#1}}
\newcommand{\acuteddot}[1]{\genericmathaccentii{\acute}{#1}}
\newcommand{\acutedddot}[1]{\genericmathaccentiii{\acute}{#1}}

\begin{document}

$\astdot{x}+\astddot{x}+\astdddot{x}$

$\circdot{x}+\circddot{x}+\circdddot{x}$

$\gravedot{x}+\graveddot{x}+\gravedddot{x}$

$\acutedot{x}+\acuteddot{x}+\acutedddot{x}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. Could you please add just one more item: either a mark resembling `\times` or a mark resembling `\circ`, but filled (preferably the latter)?

Comment: @EvanAad Did you try with `\accentset{\times}{x}` and `\accentset{\bullet}{x}`?

Comment: @EvanAad I'm not sure precisely what you want, but egreg's answer shows how to use `\accentset` to create new accents. I have used `\accentset{\bullet}{x}` to get a filled circle.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm going to take your answer's status as the preferred answer, and give it to wipet's answer instead, because (a) their solution supports automatic font size adjustment, and (b) I had to promise wipet that I would mark their answer as the preferred one if they made sure their solution worked with all the accents I was interested in.