# Error when mathematical accents are used inside scrlayer-notecolumn's makenote

Tags: accents, scrlayer-notecolumn

Consider the following LaTeX code:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage,scrlayer-notecolumn}

% The rest of the preamble is taken from
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/421866/21685
\usepackage{amsmath,accents}
\newcommand{\genericmathaccent}[2]{%
  \vbox{\offinterlineskip\ialign{%
    ##\cr
    \hidewidth$\scriptstyle#1$\hidewidth\cr
    \noalign{\kern-.5ex}
    $#2$\cr}%
  }%
}
\newcommand{\genericmathaccenti}[2]{%
  \genericmathaccent{#1{}}{#2}%
}
\newcommand{\gravedot}[1]{\genericmathaccenti{\grave}{#1}}

\begin{document}

$\gravedot{a}$%
\makenote{$\grave{a}$}
%\makenote{$\gravedot{a}$}

\end{document}
```

It compiles successfully (I use LuaLaTeX), and produces the following typeset output:

[image: makenote with a mathematical accent]

However, when I move the last `%` symbol to the line preceding it:

```
%\makenote{$\grave{a}$}
\makenote{$\gravedot{a}$}
```

compilation fails, and the following error message appears in the log file:

```
! Illegal parameter number in definition of \reserved@a.
<to be read again> 
\cr 
l.21 \makenote{$\gravedot{a}$}
                            
? 
! Emergency stop.
<to be read again> 
\cr 
l.21 \makenote{$\gravedot{a}$}
                            
End of file on the terminal!
```

What causes the error? How can it be fixed?

Comment: Either `\protect\gravedot` when in a moving argument such as `\makenote`, or use `\DeclareRobustCommand{\gravedot}{...}` instead of `\newcommand`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per egreg's [comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/604972/error-when-mathematical-accents-are-used-inside-scrlayer-notecolumns-makenote#comment1517146_604972), the issue can be fixed by defining the `\gravedot` command using `\DeclareRobustCommand` rather than with `\newcommand`:

```
\newcommand{\genericmathaccent}[2]{%
  \vbox{\offinterlineskip\ialign{%
    ##\cr
    \hidewidth$\scriptstyle#1$\hidewidth\cr
    \noalign{\kern-.5ex}
    $#2$\cr}%
  }%
}
\newcommand{\genericmathaccenti}[2]{%
  \genericmathaccent{#1{}}{#2}%
}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\gravedot}[1]{\genericmathaccenti{\grave}{#1}}
```

I've tested this solution, and it indeed works.